# Floating Action Button appears as a gray box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I'm trying to have a FAB at the bottom-right corner of my screen to float on top of the `recyclerview`.  However, the FAB is just a gray box with the widget's path.

Here is the problem:

[image]
This is my XML implementation:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/userpass_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/generate_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Have you added the design  dependency?

Comment: Yep.  Check the edit.

Comment: Have you inserted any drawable inside it? I don`t see any drawables tied to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `file>invalidate caches/restart`.  That's the issue I had with some of my widgets that were greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I did not see the image

I use this library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

version number is 1.0.0

you can have a try and clean your project cache and rebuild it.

Comment: Why do I need to add a src for FAB?

Answer (score 0):

You have added the wrong FloatingActionButton.
Implement this one and add a src attribute.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
 android:id="@+id/generate_fab"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="true" 
 android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>
```

Comment: Not really because `invalidate caches/restart` solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ExtendedFloatingActionBar` instead and set the `app:icon` to your FAB icon and don't add any text and the EFAB will look like FAB. I just don't know how to put the cradle like in FAB if you're going to place it on a Bottom Action Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate cache and restart then if it still does not appear correctly in the layout file then run the app. Once you run it, it will then appear correctly in the layout file/preview.