# Floating Action Button appears as white block on grey background

Tags: android, android-studio, floating-action-button

I have a Floating Action Button but it appears as a white block on a grey background in Android Studio's preview pane.[image: fab image]

I tried `file>invalidate caches/restart` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55863740/4232765) suggested but it did not work. Using `Android Studio 3.6.3`

I added `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'` as a dependency and used the button in xml like

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/contact_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_call_24px"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contact_details_button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It does render correctly once I run the app. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: set wrap_content  to width and height in FloatingActionButton tag

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried that but unfortunately it didn't do anything.